# MySQL group duplicate ID without loosing other data

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I'm trying to make a cookbook and  I'm having an issue with duplication. It will be easier to understand with an example, so let's begin:

My tables look like this:

```
create table Recipe (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(25), 
    description VARCHAR(50), 
    instructions VARCHAR(500)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table Ingredient (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(50)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

create table Measure (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(30)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

create table RecipeIngredient (
    recipe_id INT NOT NULL, 
    ingredient_id INT NOT NULL, 
    measure_id INT, 
    amount INT, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_recipe FOREIGN KEY(recipe_id) REFERENCES Recipe(id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingredient FOREIGN KEY(ingredient_id) REFERENCES Ingredient(id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_measure FOREIGN KEY(measure_id) REFERENCES Measure(id)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and when I run a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT r.name AS 'Recipe', 
    r.instructions, 
    ri.amount AS 'Amount', 
    mu.name AS 'Unit of Measure', 
    i.name AS 'Ingredient' 
FROM Recipe r 
JOIN RecipeIngredient ri on r.id = ri.recipe_id 
JOIN Ingredient i on i.id = ri.ingredient_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Measure mu on mu.id = measure_id;
```

I'm getting this result :

[image]

The problem is that Chocolate Cake is duplicating even though it's the same recipe it just has more than one ingredient. Could you please help me solve this problem, so I would get one instance of Recipe?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Suppose we get only one line per recipe as you want, how are you expected to display it? As in, what happens to the unit of measure, ingredient, and amount columns?

Comment: Sorry about confusion. What I would like to get is one instance of a recipe with all the ingredients. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah, you want to look at the GROUP BY clause and CONCAT function.

Comment: I'm struggling with the syntax when I try to implement your suggestion. Could you please help me out with the query?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine values from multiple rows in a group into a comma-separated list. And use `CONCAT` to concatenate strings, like concatenating the amount to the unit and ingredient.

```
SELECT r.name, r.instructions,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ri.amount, mu.name, ' ', i.name)) AS ingredients
FROM Recipe r 
JOIN RecipeIngredient ri on r.id = ri.recipe_id 
JOIN Ingredient i on i.id = ri.ingredient_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Measure mu on mu.id = measure_id
GROUP BY r.id;
```